# How to exclude results within this MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm setting up a toxi tagging system for some articles, and am using this query as a starting point for testing...

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tagmap at, articles a, tag t, userExcludedArticles uea
WHERE at.tag_id = t.tag_id
AND (t.name IN ('bookmark', 'webservice', 'semweb'))
AND a.id = at.articleID
GROUP BY a.id
```

If I have a table called userExcludedArticles (id, userID, articleID), which stores the id of articles a user has flagged as not wanting to see, how do I include that in the above query?

For testing, I have two articles in total stored in my articles table, and added both of their ids to the userExcludedArticles for userID 1 - ie this user has effectively said they don't want to be shown those two articles.

I added the following line to the query...

```
AND (uea.userID='1' AND a.id <> uea.articleID)
```

To give...

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tagmap at, articles a, tag t, userExcludedArticles uea
WHERE at.tag_id = t.tag_id
AND (t.name IN ('bookmark', 'webservice', 'semweb'))
AND a.id = at.articleID
AND (uea.userID='1' AND a.id <> uea.articleID)
GROUP BY a.id
```

But both articles appear when searching, instead of no articles.

How do I get it to return all articles that match the included tags, while excluding any articles the user has flagged as not wanting to see?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: We are not here to reverse engineer SQL queries! Reverse engineer SQL queries without example data as ascii data tables is hard to do. Also post the expected output as ascii data table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't use `GROUP BY` when you don't use aggregates in the results. MySQL allows you to use it without aggregates, but it produces random results. I assume you're using it here because including `userExcludedArticles` table gave you duplicates of the rows. That's not the proper way to handle it.

As your query is now written it will check every row in `userExcludedArticles` against every row in `articles`/`tag`/`tagmap` and if there is a row which doesn't have the article id it can be shown. This is why the articles aren't hidden.

You need to use `NOT EXISTS` clause to check for this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tagmap at, articles a, tag t
WHERE at.tag_id = t.tag_id
AND (t.name IN ('bookmark', 'webservice', 'semweb'))
AND a.id = at.articleID
AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 from userExcludedArticles
     WHERE userID='1' AND a.id = articleID)
```

Now you don't need `GROUP BY` since there aren't multiple results per article and the articles are hidden if the `userExcludedArticles` contains a row with the article's id regardless of any other rows.

Also would be better to use `JOIN` syntax for the tables rather than multiple in the `FROM` section.

Comment: uhm "First, don't use GROUP BY when you don't use aggregates in the results. MySQL allows this" Every database i know allows the use GROUP BY without aggregates.."MySQL allows this, but it produces random results" most off the time when you use SELECT a.*... GROUP BY a.id MySQL could produce random results yes.. but if column id is a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY the query is ansi SQL valid and you won't get random results.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, *with* aggregates. The point is not to use them *without* aggregates. Every MySQL installation should have the settings so that this isn't allowed, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: "First, don't use GROUP BY when you don't use aggregates in the results. MySQL allows this" if you mean using GROUP BY without aggregates doesn't make sense then your right...